# Looking for an efficient way to find specific subfolders in a folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to come up with a faster/more efficient way to scan a folder and find the subfolders of interest.

Below is what I have. It works fine for test cases, where I'm trying to find, say, a dozen folders of interest in a folder that contains, say, a hundred or so subfolders.

However, it chokes in my real-world case, where I'm trying to find around 100 subfolders of interest in a folder that contains around 300,000 subfolders plus a few text files.

I feel like there should be a faster/more efficient way to do this, because I have some MATLAB code that's doing the same thing (i.e. scanning a folder for subfolders of interest) and it works fine. However, for corporate reasons, I need to move from MATLAB to Python.

For what it's worth, I'm running this as a Jupyter notebook.

```
import os
import re

def find_subfolders_of_interest(dir_of_interest, starting_string_of_interest):
    all_subfolders = [item for item in os.listdir(dir_of_interest) if os.path.isdir(dir_of_interest, item))]

    startWithPattern = starting_string_of_interest
    regexp_pattern = re.compile(startsWithPattern)

    all_subfolders_of_interest = list(filter(regexp_pattern.match, all_subfolders))
    return all_subfolders_of_interest

def main():
    all_subfolders_of_interest = find_subfolders_of_interest('test_folder', 'string_of_interest')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In what sense does this "choke"?

Comment: It takes >30 minutes for a response to appear.  I frequently just give up and quit the program.   Hamza NABIL's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.scandir](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/), The [example from the documentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/#examples):

```py
def subdirs(path):
    """Yield directory names not starting with '.' under given path."""
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_dir():
            yield entry.name
```

You can customize it:

```py
def find_subfolders_of_interest(dir_of_interest, starting_string_of_interest):
    all_subfolders_of_interest = []

    for entry in os.scandir(dir_of_interest):
        if entry.name.startswith(starting_string_of_interest) and entry.is_dir():
            all_subfolders_of_interest.append(entry.name)

    return all_subfolders_of_interest
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for - it's even similar to the way I was doing things in MATLAB.  I just didn't know about the os.scandir() function.